# Disallow Crawling of All Search Pages

Tags: google, google-search-console, web-crawlers, robots.txt, googlebot

Using `robots.txt` I am attempting to stop all crawling of search URLs

```
Disallow: /rest_of_url/search&tour*
```

Above is what I am using. Our URL looks like the following for all search results. However, everything after `search&tour` can be different, for example:

```
https://www.example.com.au/rest_of_url/search&tour-sdfs=the-palce+lcation+&tour-duration=1/
```

Will the `Disallow` code above stop robots from crawling all of my search result pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the Disallow code above stop robots from crawling all of my search result pages?

Yes, it will stop the (good) bots that obey the robots.txt "standard".

However, you don't need the trailing `*`. `robots.txt` is *prefix matching*, so the "wildcard" `*` at the end can simply be omitted. (Wildcard type matches are an extension of the original standard anyway.)

And you obviously need the `User-agent` directive that precedes this rule, if you haven't got it already:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /rest_of_url/search&tour
```

Comment: I've applied this method because of the structure of my CMS. Thank you - your information was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Disallow sets the files or folders that are not allowed to be crawled.

In addition, you can prevent a page from appearing in Google Search by including a noindex meta tag in the page's HTML code. When Googlebot next crawls that page, Googlebot will see the noindex meta tag and will drop that page entirely from Google Search results, regardless of whether other sites link to it.

Comment: Thank you for your response - this would of been perfect but the structure of my CMS would mean it would effect other pages by adding this to the template